# How do I increase the size of an embedded image in an RStudio Rpres file

Tags: r, rstudio

Currently the code for title slide is as follows and I want the image to fill the entire slide

```
R-Squared Risk Management
========================================
author: Arun Soni
font-family: 'Arial'
css: R-Squared Presentation.css

![alt text](figures/r-presentation Title Page.png)

<small><small><small>http://www.rsqrm.com</small></small></small>

First Slide
========================================================

For more details on authoring R presentations click the
**Help** button on the toolbar.

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```